# How to get the parameters of an inline delegate?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know if there is way to get the sender and the eventarguments passed to an event when using an inline delegate like below?

```
p.Click+=delegate
    {
        //do some stuff                
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can declare it:

```
p.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) {...}
```

and use them as `sender` and `args`.

Or with lambdas:

```
p.Click += (sender, args) => {...}
```